# Nth root Swift render

Tags: ios, swift

I have mathematical application. I have problem nth root. I am using `mathJax` library for rendering result. User enter result will be in the `textview`. I need to display cube root and nth root in IOS. Once user tap nth root key, it shows  `√(n)(x)` here user has to remove n and type root value and root.

Swift code

```
func replaceNTHRootEquation(equation : String)->String{
    print("===equation==:\(equation)")
    let newString = equation.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("√\\((.*)\\)\\((.*)\\)", withString: "root($2)^(1/$1)")
    print("===newString==:\(newString)")

    return newString
}
```

I will work like this, when user press, nth root it will display in the `textview` like `√(n)(x) , then user delete`n`and type value like`x` also.

Current my problem is that I am passing the initial equation like `√(n)(x)` this but `replaceNTHRootEquation` method return same result. Not `root(3)(27)`

This is not replacing the string //√(3)(27) always. Not give like  [image: this result]

Please suggest idea

Answer (score 1):

`"√((.*))((.*))"` won't capture `√(3)(27)` as you expected because the outer brackets aren't escaped. As they are, they are being interpreted as capture groups, such that:

- `(.*)` is your first capture group (`$1`)
- `.*` is your first capture group (`$2`)
- `(.*)` is your first capture group (`$3`)
- `.*` is your first capture group (`$4`)

You need to escape the bracket by prepending a `\`, to indicate that you intend for the bracket to be interpreted literally as a bracket, rather than as a capture group start/end. However, `\` already has a reserved meaning, in that it starts various Swift-related escape sequences. Thus, you need to escape the `\` as well with another slash, to indicate that you intend for the slash to be interpreted literally as a slash, and not the start of an escape sequence. Like so:

`"√\\((.*)\\)\\((.*)\\)"`

Comment: I have added \\ earlier. No Luck.

Comment: Okay, well have you considered describing the errors you're getting, your input, your desired input, etc.? You're giving us little to work with here...

Comment: Sure. I have updated question. My problem is `replaceNTHRootEquation` method return same result. Not `root(3)(27)`

Comment: What does "returning the same result" mean? Same as what?